# How to determine the class of a pseudo-homogeneous kernel that depend on a diagonal matrice

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, functional-analysis, improper-integrals, singular-integrals

Let $D$ be a $3\times3$ diagonal real matrice and denote by $|\cdot|$ the euclidian norm in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
I want to find the class of the following singular kernel:
$$
\frac{1}{|x-y|}-\frac{1}{|D(x-y)|},\; x,y\in\mathbb{R}^3, x\neq y
$$

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by the expression $D(x-y)$? With $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$, the expression $x-y$ is a scalar, so are you simply multiplying the matrix $D$ by a scalar?

Comment: @Anurag A: thank you, I edited it.